# On the asymptotic behaviour as $X\to\infty$ of the sum $\sum\frac{1}{x}$ over every $x\leq X$ such that $\pi_2(x)<2C_2\int_2^x\frac{dt}{\log^2t} $

Tags: asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, twin-primes

Let $\pi_2(x)$ the twin prime-counting function that counts the number of twin primes $p,p+2$ with $p\leq x$, and $C_2$ is the the twin prime constant. We assume the Twin Prime conjecture, see it as Conjecture 3, the definition of $C_2$ and the figure 1  here in this [Sebah and Gourdon, *Introduction to twin primes and Brun’s constant
computation*, (2002) from numbers.computation.free.fr](http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/Primes/twin.pdf).

I am wondering if is it possible state a similar asymptotic, for twin primes on assumption of the Twin Prime conjecture as I've said in previous paragraph, studied by Rubinstein and Sarnak. The identity that I am saying appears for example in page 221 of [Granville and Martin, *Carreras de números primos*, La Gaceta de la Real Sociedad Matemática Española, Vol 8.1 (2005)](http://gaceta.rsme.es/vernumero.php?id=57) (in spanish, there is a version in english edited with title *Prime Number Races* from the American Mathematical Monthly, at 2006).

I believe that this question is not in the literature but maybe is related to the calculation in the Apéndice II of previous paper from La Gaceta.

> **Question.** We assume previous Twin Prime conjecture and we imagine that our purpose should be write a similar statement for twin primes than Sarnak and Rubinstein wrote for prime numbers. Then I believe that the first step should be:
>
> Calculate the asymptotic behaviour of
> $$\sum_{x\leq X:\pi_2(x)<2C_2\int_2^x\frac{dt}{\log^2t}}\frac{1}{x},$$ as $X\to\infty$. Can you provide the calculations or hints to get this asymptotic behaviour?

*Reference:*

[1] Hardy and Littlewood, *Some problems of ‘Partitio numerorum’; III: On the expression of a number as a sum of primes*, Acta Math. Vol. 44 (1923).

Comment: Many thanks for your attention and help @Did

Comment: I am agree that this question wasn't the best in my learning of mathematics. Many thanks for the patience. Now my intention/purpose is draw attention to get more contributions/feedback about this question, and select in next days, when expires the bounty, definitively an answer. I accept that the answer below is very good. And I will be happy if in next future some user with good mathematical knowledges want to ask a related question in MathOverflow.

Comment: C'est pourtant évident : lis les livres au lieu d'inventer des formules. Ce qu'on sait faire y est expliqué. Ce qui n'y est pas expliqué c'est qu'en général on ne **sait pas** le faire (apostol, titchmarsh, ivic, pattersson, iwaniec...)

Comment: Many thanks always @user1952009 . Thanks to the presence of mathematicians like you, this site is possible. And you are right about the importance of books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a natural one, and I'm not sure why this has been downvoted.

While it may be true the the logarithmic density exists, we have little to no idea how to prove this, even after assuming many conjectures about the zeros of the Riemann Zeta function. To understand why, let's look at the ingredients in Rubenstein and Sarnak's theorem. They need to assume the validity of two major conjectures:

- (1) The Riemann Hypothesis (RH)
- (2) The Linear Independence Hypothesis (LI)

The Riemann Hypothesis is equivalent to having a very strong bound on the error term when counting primes, that is RH is equivalent to
$$|E(x)|\ll_\epsilon x^{\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon}$$ for any $\epsilon>0$, where $$E(x)=\pi(x)-\text{li}(x).$$ The Linear Independence Hypothesis assumes that all of the imaginary parts zeros of zeta are independent over the rationals, and this is used to obtain finer grain distributional information about the behavior of $E(x)$. Putting these together, they can obtain results for the logarithmic density of the set of points where $\pi(x)>\text{li}(x)$.

---

**Twin Primes:**
Moving on to the problem for twin primes, analogous to $(1)$ we would need to obtain a strong bound on the size of the error term $$|E_2(x)|=\left|\pi_2(x)-2C_2\int_2^x \frac{1}{\log^2 t} dt\right|,$$ and analogous to $(2)$ we would need a very strong assumption that allows us to obtain distributional information for the size of the error term. However, unlike in the case for primes, we do not even know how to provide $(1)$ - we do not know what the size of this error term should be, even under the assumption of the Riemann Hypothesis or the Generalized Riemann Hypothesis. In fact, we can't even disprove obviously wrong statements such as 
$$\left|\pi_2(x)-2C_2\int_2^x \frac{1}{\log^2 t} dt\right|<C$$
for some fixed constant $C$. The error term should almost certainly grow like $x^{\frac{1}{2}+o(1)}$ but we don't know how to prove anything here. Given that we are unable to obtain the right size of the error term, distributional information is out of the question.

So while your question is a natural one, currently it is not known how to prove anything close to that, even under the strongest assumptions about the distributions of the zeros of zeta.

Comment: Also the reason that Rubinstein and Sarnak can say anything about $E(x)$ is that they can find an explicit expression for it in terms of the zeroes of $\zeta(s)$; it is this expression that allows them to conditionally prove the existence of a limiting logarithmic distribution for $E(x)$. Of course, for twin primes, we have no idea of what $E_2(x)$ should look like and whether it should have any relation to zeroes of a zeta function.

Comment: @PeterHumphries: Exactly. I believe it was Heath-Brown that asked the question "Is $|E_2(x)|<C?$ to highlight how little we know about the error term. (Although I'm not sure if there's a reference in writing anywhere)

Comment: Perfect explanation! Many thanks to you, Humphries, user1952009 and especially to @ProfessorVector

Answer (score 0):

If you read the spanish article carefully, you'll notice that Rubinstein and Sarnak proved their results under very strong assumptions, one of them being the Generalized Riemann Hypothesis, using an explicit formula for the prime counting function $\pi(x)$ (in terms of the zeroes of the zeta function). There isn't anything like that we would know or conjecture about twin primes, as far as I know.

Comment: Many thanks for your attention and answer. First, I understand some of the paragraphs of this nice paper about prime number races, from an informative viewpoint. Secondly I do not know if my question has mathematical meaning 100%. I am an amateur mathematician, so if in next future you want to expand your answer, if you consider it,  it is  appreciated.

Comment: @user243301 In number theory, I'm an amateur (or aficionado, if you'd prefer that) myself. I'm afraid I'll be able to expand my anser only after further progress in that area, and while there _is_ progress in the twin prime mystery (mainly thanks to the excellent work of Terence Tao and others), I'm not sure it will go in the direction you dream of (at least, not soon enough far enough).